# Modelling a "one to one or two" relationship

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have an uncommon database design problem I'm not sure how to handle properly. There is a table called `profile` storing a website users' public profile information. However, every profile can belong to either a single person or a couple so I need an additional child table called `person` to store person-specific data. Every `profile` entity must have at least one but no more than two `person` child entities.

What is the best (in terms of being "kosher" and/or performance) way to model such relationship? Should I go with regular one-to-many and enforce the number of children programatically or with stored procedures? Or should I just create two foreign key fields in the parent table and allow `null` for one of them? Maybe there's another way I can't think of?

**Edit:** Additional info in response to Gordon's questions

- A person can be related to only one profile and there can't be a person without a profile. Perhaps the name `person` is confusing, as it may suggest that a person has profile, while in fact it's the profile that has person information.
- In case of couple profiles both persons are equal. Due to the site's specific the limit on 2 will never change, however it should be possible to add or remove a person (to make a single person profile a couple profile and vice-versa) but there can never be less than 1 or more than 2 persons.
- The person data would never be fetched without the profile data but the profile data could sometimes be fetched without the person data.

Comment: Having two fields will make it more difficult to select/join on them. In my experience it is better to go with the one to many relation and enforce it when the data is modified (via stored procs, triggers or application logic). Edit: this is valid for MySQL, not sure about other RDBMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1)

The solution with two fields:

- PRO: Allows you to precisely restrict both minimal and maximal number of people per proflie.
- CON: Would allow a profile-less person.
- CON: Would require 2 indexes (1 on each field) to efficiently get the profile of a given person, taking additional space and potentially slowing down INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

## 2)

But if you are willing to enforce the minimal number at the application level, you might be better off with something like this:

[image]

```
CHECK(PERSON_NO = 1 OR PERSON_NO = 2)
```

Characteristics:

- CON: Allows a person-less profile.
- PRO: Restricts maximal number of people per profile, yet easy to change by just modifying the CHECK.
- PRO: If you keep the identifying relationship as above, it doesn't require additional indexes and is [clustering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index)-friendly (persons of the same profile can be stored physically close together, minimizing I/O during JOIN).

On the other hand, if you have a key PERSON_ID (or similar), then an additional index on {PROFILE_ID, PERSON_NO} would be necessary for the efficient enforcement of key constraint on these fields too.

## 3)

Theoretically, you could even combine the two approaches and avoid **both** profile-less persons and person-less profiles:

[image]

(PERSON1_ID is not NULL-able, PERSON2_ID is NULL-able)

However, this leads to circular references, requiring deferred constraints to resolve, which are unfortunately not supported by MySQL.

## 4)

And finally, you could just take a brute-force approach and simply place fields of both persons in the profile table (and make one of these sets not NULL-able and the other NULL-able).

---

Out of all these possibilities, I'd probably go with 2).

Answer (score 1):

You essentially have two options, as you mention in your question.  You can store two fields in the table.  Or, you can have a second table that has the mapping information.

Here are some additional question to help you answer the question:

- Can a person have their own profile and a profile as part of a couple?
- Are both people on a profile "equal" or is one the "master" and the other an "alternate"?
- When you fetch profile information, will you always be including information about all people on the profile?
- Can you have persons without profiles?

In this case, I just have the sneaky suspicion that the limit on "2" may change in the future.  This suggests storing the mapping in a separate table, since increasing "2" by adding a field is a problem in terms of modifying existing code.  In other words, creating a separate table, person-profile, that maps persons to profiles. In mysql, you can always gather the person-level information using GROUP_CONCAT().

One case where it is better to put such similar fields in the same table is when one is clearly preferred and the other is the alternate.  In that case, you are doing a lot of "coalesce(, )" type of logic.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I edited the original post to answer your questions.